# Wrapping allocated output parameters with a scoped_ptr/array

Tags: boost, memory-management, output-parameter

So,
I have some code which looks like this:

```
byte* ar;
foo(ar) // Allocates a new[] byte array for ar 
...
delete[] ar;
```

To make this safer, I used a scoped_array:

```
byte* arRaw;
scoped_array<byte> ar;
foo(arRaw);
ar.reset(arRaw);
...
// No delete[]
```

The question is, Is there any existing way to do this using just the scoped_array, without using a temporary raw array?

I can probably write an in-place "resetter" class, just wondering if the functionality exists and I'm missing it.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just pass a reference to the scoped array to foo and call reset inside of foo?

Alternatively have foo return a boost::shared_array/ptr as follows

```
boost::shared_array<byte> foo()
{
  boost::shared_array<byte> a (new byte[100]);
  return a;
}

boost::shared_array<byte> ar = foo();
```

Edit:

Since you cannot change foo how about the following?

```
byte* rawArray;
foo (rawArray);
boost::scoped_array<byte> array (rawArray);
```

Alternatively you can overload foo as follows

```
boost::shared_array<byte> foo()
{
    byte* rawArray;
    foo (rawArray);
    return boost::shared_arry<byte> (rawArray);
}
```

and then use the overloaded version as follows

```
boost::shared_array<byte> array = foo();
```

Comment: foo is given, and I don't want to change it. I want to enforce the safety from the scope which is calling foo.

Comment: I like the overload suggestion, it provides more encapsulation. Thanks!